# Code Coverage for IF statement

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

May I know how I can create a code coverage for if statement code? Here is my if statement code:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void submitFinalApproval(Id recordId) {

        //1. RS
        if(String.valueOf(recordId).startsWith('a0O')){
            update new Return_Shipment__c(Id = recordId, Final_Approved__c = true); 
        }
        //2. VO__c
        if(String.valueOf(recordId).startsWith('a0G')){
            update new VO__c(Id = recordId, Final_Approved__c = true); 
        }
        //3. RPR__c
        if(String.valueOf(recordId).startsWith('a0A')){
            update new RPR__c(Id = recordId, Final_Approved__c = true); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't hardcode key prefixes. You don't even need to check them at all. Just check `recordId.getSObjectType()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily make this 100% coverable by changing the code as follows:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void submitFinalApproval(Id recordId) {
    sObject record = recordId.getSObjectType().newSobject(recordId);
    record.put('Final_Approved__c',true);
    update record;
}
```

You can read more about this in the relevant document: [Dynamic DML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_dml.htm) and [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm). Writing the unit test for this should be trivial at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I want to ask in the sobject, I do not have any record type, do I still can use this?

recordId.getSObjectType().newSobject(recordId);

Comment: @Atiqah Yes, an sobjectType is not the same as a Record Type. You don't need a Record Type to use this method.